# HTML5 Background Animation onScroll, Best Practice

Tags: html, animation, background

I'm looking for a way to implement some animation on the background on a page when the user scrolls down a page. Think of ... maybe a divided sphere which get closer when the user scrolls down the page and get departed on a scroll up.

I thought of using SVG in combination of JS, but maybe some of you know better ways to implement that kind of stuff.

Maybe some of you already coded that kind of animation?

PS: I don't want to use Flash etc., just HTML5 and existing frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I found some frameworks, plugins that do exactly I was looking for and I don't want to hold them back. Here are the links:

- [Scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/)
- [Scrolldeck, Parallax](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/decks/parallax/)

Have a nice day! :)

Sy